# Ruby 2.3 squiggly heredoc syntax not recognized in RubyMine

Tags: ruby, rubymine, ruby-2.3

I'm using RubyMine to write code for an app that's using Ruby 2.3.

I have RubyMine set to use Ruby 2.3 (I've tried the auto-detected rbenv 2.3.0 and also pointing to the binary manually):

[image: rubymine using version 2.3]

But it doesn't work with the [new squiggly heredoc syntax](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9098#note-6). Observe:

[image: the code is good]

[image: but RubyMine doesn't like it]

How can I make RubyMine recognize my squiggly heredocs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait for a version of the RubyMine 8.5 EAP release that fixes [RubyMine issue 17637](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-17637#tab=Linked%20Issues). That issue has two sub-issues related to code insight for squiggly heredocs. They have no affected version yet. You can star them to get an email when they change. You can also keep an eye on the summary of RubyMine 8.5 release notes on JetBrains' wiki, follow them [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/rubymine) or follow [their blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/ruby/).

Comment: This is fixed in the new release. :)